# How do I update a nested key of a JsObject in scala

Tags: json, scala

In my code I make a get request to a server to get some json, and then I want to update one of the values before I send it back. I know that if the key was on the top level I could just update the key by writing

```
val newConfig = originalConfig ++ Json.obj("key" -> newValue)
```

however I cannot figure out a nice way to update it if the key I want to change is a couple of layers in.

ie. My json looks like this, and I want to just update key5

```
{
    "key1": "value",
    "key2": {
        "key3": "value",
        "key4": {
            "key5": "value",
            "key6": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without updating it layer by layer?
ie.

```
val key4 = originalKey4 ++ Json.obj("key5" -> newValue)
val key2 = originalKey2 ++ Json.obj("key4" -> key4)
val newJson = originalJson ++ Json.obj("key2" -> key2)
```

The actual key that I want to update is 7 layers in, so this is rather tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at [json transformers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers)

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val str = """{
            |    "key1": "value",
            |    "key2": {
            |        "key3": "value",
            |        "key4": {
            |            "key5": "value",
            |            "key6": "value"
            |        }
            |    }
            |}""".stripMargin

val json = Json.parse(str)

val transformer = (__ \ 'key2 \ 'key4 \ 'key5).json.update(
  __.read[JsString].map(_ => Json.toJson("updated value"))
)

val result = json.transform(transformer).asOpt.get

Json.prettyPrint(result)

res0: String = {
  "key1" : "value",
  "key2" : {
    "key3" : "value",
    "key4" : {
      "key5" : "updated value",
      "key6" : "value"
    }
  }
}
```